# Formula for calculate the number of the given day of year

Tags: c

I have to write a program that asks the user for a day and month. Next, it should print the day number of the year for the given day and month. Assume that the year is a leap year.

I devised a formula to avoid using too many conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int day, month, dayOfYear;
    
    puts("Give me a day and a month and i'll give you the number of year day!");
    scanf("%d %d", &day, &month);

    
    /* (month / 2) is used for add the extra day of the months with 31 days. */

    dayOfYear = (month - 1) * 30 + day + (month / 2);
    
    
    /*All the months are calculated of 30 days, so, after of February 29 it's 
     *substrated one day to compensate the remaining day. For non-leap years, substract 
     *two.
     */

    if(month > 2)
    {
        dayOfYear -= 1;
    } 
    
    
    printf("The day of the year: %d\n", dayOfYear);
    return 0;
}
```

I was spend many hours finding a way to do short and understandible. I wrote here because i hope that could can be useful for someone.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is -- this site is a Q/A format, not an annoucement

Comment: The long and short months do not strictly alternate, so your technique "(month / 2) is used for add the extra day of the months with 31 days", though clever, is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK to answer you own question; [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), yet important to get it right.

OP's approach fails for month 9 and 11.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"

int doy2021(int month, int day) {
  int dayOfYear = (month - 1) * 30 + day + (month / 2);
  if (month > 2) {
    dayOfYear -= 2; // 2021
  }
  return dayOfYear;
}

int main() {
  for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
    struct tm first_of_the_month = {.tm_year = 2021 - 1900, .tm_mon = m - 1,
        .tm_mday = 1, .tm_hour = 12};
    mktime(&first_of_the_month);
    // int tm_yday; // days since January 1 -- [0, 365]
    printf("Month:%2d  doy(mktime):%3d  doy(Juan):%3d\n", m,
        first_of_the_month.tm_yday + 1, doy2021(m, 1));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Ouput

```
Month: 1  doy(mktime):  1  doy(Juan):  1
Month: 2  doy(mktime): 32  doy(Juan): 32
Month: 3  doy(mktime): 60  doy(Juan): 60
Month: 4  doy(mktime): 91  doy(Juan): 91
Month: 5  doy(mktime):121  doy(Juan):121
Month: 6  doy(mktime):152  doy(Juan):152
Month: 7  doy(mktime):182  doy(Juan):182
Month: 8  doy(mktime):213  doy(Juan):213
Month: 9  doy(mktime):244  doy(Juan):243 Differ
Month:10  doy(mktime):274  doy(Juan):274
Month:11  doy(mktime):305  doy(Juan):304 Differ
Month:12  doy(mktime):335  doy(Juan):335
```

Answer (score 0):

Becareful about leap year.
From Wikipedia 'leap year' for gregorian calendrar :

if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)
else if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)
else if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)
else (it is a leap year)

You are taking too much leap.

Comment: In the question it was stated, "Assume that the year is a leap year."